# How to use or access Azure Linux VM from a Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I want to use a linux VM in Azure. I would like to install Docker in that machine, but I will be using my Windows 10 laptop for accessing it. How do I do it?

Comment: Access the docker? do you mean you just want to connect it?

Comment: why not install docker on your machine? easier\faster\more convenient. it can even run linux containers natively

Comment: I can't use Docker in my machine. I can install it but when I run it, my RAM which is 2GB only is not sufficient. So I figured why not install it in a remote host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to install Docker in that machine, but I will be using my
>   Windows 10 laptop for accessing it. How do I do it?

If you just want to access the docker, like `ping` or `http`, maybe we can follow those steps to do it:
1.Install docker on Azure VM.
2.create docker on it, like this:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image service nginx start
```

After this docker create complated, the nginx will map on port 80.

3.We should add port 80 on Azure NSG, we can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal) to add inbound rules.

Then we can use windows 10 to access the VM's public IP address with port 80.

---

**Update:**

If you are using Azure container service(kubernetes), we should use `kubectl` command to create docker.

We can use this script(Azure CLI 2.0) to connect to Azure container service(AKS):

```
az login -u xxx@domain.com -p xxxx
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=myResourceGroup --name=myK8sCluster
```

Then we can use docker file(yml) to create application, like this:

```
kubectl create -f azure-vote.yml
```

In this way, your local window 10 can connect to ACS K8S.

hope this helps:)

Comment: if the VM is being used in a Kubernetes cluster, does it already have Docker inside it? To be honest this is a task given to me by the person who owns the Azure Account. But he gave me access to it, and the task is to learn how to deploy my Golang Rest API code as a microservice to the Kubernetes VM. But I can't even run Docker in my machine

Comment: Do you mean Azure container service kubernetes? you want to deploy docker in it or access the docker?

Comment: if you are use kubernetes cluster, you should create docker via `kubectl` command, first you should connect to Azure K8S cluster then to create docker on it. If he have create the docker, he should push the docker as a service to public, then you access the docker's public IP. please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-walkthrough).

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 I have update my answer, please check it. Please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: I'm using az aks get-credentials --resource-group=myResourceGroup --name=myClusterName but response says my client does not have authorization to perform action

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Windows client? use windows client to deploy AKS?

Comment: I'm doing that in a windows server 2016 machine, in a client

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Have you login Azure ? run `az login ` command?

Comment: I've logged in before and I can `az acr login --name <acrname>` without any problem. I think I have a problem with ssh, what's the ssh command I need to access it? I did not create the cluster nor the resource group but I was assigned global admin

Comment: @JohnStephen.19  When we run `az aks get-credentials` need credentials(privaye), could you check `.azure` under your user.

Comment: pardon? I don't get what you just suggested. Just realized ssh doesn't have anyhing to do with this authorization issue

Comment: btw, another thing. In get-credentials what I put after the --name flag is the resource with type Container Service

Comment: I was expecting that since I was assigned as global admin, I have the necessary permissions for almost all tasks, but it doesn't even let me create a new resource group. So something must still be changed

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Do you mean you can't run this command? `az group create --name myResourceGroup --location eastus`

Comment: no I can't. `The client 'live.com#johnstephensoriao19@outlook.com' with object id xxx does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope 'subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/samplegroup'. But the account admin says he already assigned me as owner and global admin, so he expects I would be able to do those things

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 could you please check you Azure ad user `Directory role`, make sure the directory role is `Global administrator`?

Comment: Global Admin. But directory role is greyed out so I can't edit it

Comment: Please check subscription role.

Comment: I'm more confused now. When I entered this command before `az acr list --resource-group myResourceGroup --query "[].{acrLoginServer:loginServer}" --output table`, it outputs our acr server. Now, there's no error but there's no output either. I **CAN** push my images into the container registry though. `kubectl create -f xxx.yml` says _you must be logged in to the server_.Meanwhile, `az aks get-credentials --resource-group=rgrp --name=clustername` says _the resource xxx under resource group xxx was not found_

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Sorry for the delay, could you please run this command to list your AKS `az aks list --resource-group rgrp`?

Comment: output is open and close squre bracket `[]`

Comment: it seems there is no cluster in that resource group. can you check it via Azure portal, try to find the cluster in which group.

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Please let me know if you need more help:)